# After upgrading magento from v2.1.16 6o v 2.2.5 getting error in static content deployement

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, deployment

After successfully upgrade Magento from **2.1.16 to 2.2.5** when deploying the static content it throwing the below error, further debug to check file is present in the vendor folder.

***Check Below Error in the console -***

```
lenovo@lenovo-ThinkCentre-E73:/var/www/creativeroxyogi$ sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
[sudo] password for lenovo: 

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            910/1016            =========================>-- 89% %   7 secs
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: /var/www/creativeroxyogi/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]                                                                                                                                                        
  Cannot read contents from file "/var/www/creativeroxyogi/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.css" Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/creativeroxyogi/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank  
  /en_US/css/styles-m.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried giving write permissions to pub/static ?

Comment: Yes I provide permission and delete the cache and generated folder as well but no luck